Does self-similarity of a geometric configuration always imply an algebraic relation?
This thought occurred to me a while ago. I noticed in two quite dissimilar cases that, for a configuration of points and lines in the plane which had a self-similarity of some kind, an algebraic relation involving the lengths in the configuration could be derived.
So I write "a self-similarity of some kind": this is admittedly vague, but I hope the following two examples will serve as evidence that it might be possible to assign a more definite meaning to this phrase. Provisionally, still not quite precise but getting there, I would define it as the property that the configuration can be decomposed into a set of sub-configurations which are all mutually similar.

The first comes from the Dutch Mathematical Olympiad 2017, First Round, Problem A7 (click here for the English version). This is actually a neat little puzzle. Given the configuration of squares as below, find the ratio between the sides of the rectangle:
The self-similarity of this figure needs no further elaboration, since it is wholly composed of squares. From the self-similarity we may in this case derive a linear relation between lengths.

The second example comes from a quite different corner: the Pythagorean theorem. Of course, one of the most elegant and well-known proofs comes from dividing a right-angled triangle into two subtriangles, both similar to the original one:In this case, the self-similarity of the figure does not give a linear, but a quadratic relation between the lengths, as the Pythagorean theorem teaches us. [As an aside, there is a different proof, which from a Google search seems to be even more popular:The above configuration does not fit my definition of "self-similar," but nevertheless it feels close in spirit, which to me suggests that we may also ask the question with a broader understanding of the term "self-similar."]


With this explanation and with these examples, I rest my case. Are they just two isolated example of "self-similar geometric configurations" in which the self-similarity implies an algebraic relation between lengths, or is there something more general going on?

Your question answers itself. Any definition of "similarity" is essentially equivalent to "lengths of line segments are proportional".
Then in the Euclidean plane, areas of similar figures are proportional to the squares of corresponding lengths.
(The existence of similar triangles is in fact equivalent to the parallel postulate and to the Pythagorean theorem -  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate .)

I think the word “algebraic” is the key content to this question. Similar means direct constant of proportionality but is that constant a rational, quadratic rational, cubic rational etc… they also need to be more specific about what constitutes a geometric question. An example might be “given a diagram of line segments, where certain angles are marked equivalent and certain lengths are marked the same can a side length in the diagram ever be a non algebraic multiple of another side length”. This becomes an abstract algebra question.

I now realize that when I write "algebraic relation between lengths," this is not specific enough. In both examples, we start with a very simple configuration (rectangle or triangle), for which a self-similar subdivision exists, and we end up with a relation between lengths in the original configuration. I grant that the very fact of self-similarity gives us relations between lengths by definition, but it seems kind of striking to me that these relations sort of "trickle down" to give also a relation between the lengths in the original figure.

So while I must thank you because your objection makes me realize that my question needed sharpening, I am not ready yet to concede that my question answers itself. :-) On the other hand, it could be that the sharpened version of the question has a counterexample. I will think about it further and see if I can edit the question to make it clearer.

I would accept this answer @R.P. And then ask your sharpened question later or even ask “how do I sharpen this to meaningfully convey my intent” and then make your intent as explicit as possible.
